# URL recording after the URI in google Analytics All Data view?

Tags: url, google-analytics

In my Google analytics account, All data view is recording URL after URI. When I click on the page it shows not found. I am attaching a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have the domain after the URI...

```
/my-account/skillatwill.com

should be:

skillatwill.com/my-account/
```

Surely this is a problem.

Then, if you hang the domain on your URI, when you click to open the Analytics page, it will hang it up again, so it will still give you an error. The click function to open the pages works only if you save in Analytics the URI without the domain.